# Retrieving path to dotted-in script

Tags: bash

Getting at the path to a running script in bash is trivial via the `$0` variable.  However, it doesn't work if you are being dotted in via another script, instead you will get the path to the calling script.  Consider the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script1.sh
echo $(readlink -f $0)
```

...

```
#!/bin/bash
# script2.sh
. /tmp/script1.sh
echo $(readlink -f $0)
```

The output from the above script is:

```
/tmp/script2.sh
/tmp/script2.sh
```

However, if `$0` in a dotted-in script emitted the path to that script, the output would instead be:

```
/tmp/script1.sh
/tmp/script2.sh
```

How can I get that correct value?

Comment: FYI -- `echo "$(readlink -f "$0")"` would be a more correct formulation. And `$0` is *always* suspect; see [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), including the section at the end ("Why $0 is NOT an option").

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this (specific to bash) you can use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`

```
#!/bin/bash
# script1.sh
real_dollar_zero=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
echo $(readlink -f $real_dollar_zero)
```

Now the output is:

```
/tmp/script1.sh
/tmp/script2.sh
```

Viola! - `The strung musical instrument often confused with a violin!`

Comment: I think you mean *voila* (or more properly *voilà*), it's French for "see here".

Comment: I think you are correct.  I actually didn't mean the musical instrument at all!  Less haste, more speed. :-)  I'll leave it in there for humour's sake.

Comment: As a French, `viola` mean rapped... So I hope/think/suppose that @tripleee is right :)

Comment: BTW, consider `readlink -f "$real_dollar_zero"` -- without the quotes, file or directory names with spaces will misbehave (as will some other, less likely scenarios).